# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: "SpeechKitApplicationKey"

Tags: ios, objective-c, frameworks, speech-recognition

I followed every step on adding a SpeechKit framework to my app, but I cannot get it to work.
After building an app, i get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
"_SpeechKitApplicationKey", referenced from:
  l069 in SpeechKit(libSpeechKit.a-i386-master.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see    invocation)
```

I added SpeechKit framework from Project-Build Phases-Link Binary With Libraries 
And I have included all the necessary frameworks that are needed in order for it to work:

1. Foundation
2. System Configuration
3. Audio Toolbox
4. CFNetwork
5. AVFoundation
6. Security

Valid architectures, in my bBuild Settings are armv7m armv7s arc64

Comment: can you paste the headers of you m and h file ? sometimes const values tend to return that

Comment: Which file exactly ?@EmilDo

Comment: I have added the SpeechKitApplicationKey to my project, still I get the same error. Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the key in your sources

```
 const unsigned char[] SpeechKitApplicationKey = {0x12, 0x34, ..., 0x89};
```

You need to get the key before using the library.

See the [documentation](https://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/SpeechKit_Guide/ServerConnection.html) for more details.